# try catch issue with deadlock

Tags: php, mysql, try-catch, deadlock

i use below code -[Just try again.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-deadlocks.html) - to prevent deadlock.

it seems when code goes to catch part query2 run before  query1.

and i see this output "query2 run before query 1";
    is it true?

```
    try 
    {
    $query1="....";
    }
    catch
    {
    $query1="....";//repeat query1 in try
    $t1=microtime();
    }
    $query2="....";
    $t2=microtime();
    if ($t2<$t1)
{
echo "query2 run before query 1";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not true

```
echo '1';
try {
 echo '2';
 throw new Exception;
} catch (Exception $e) {
 echo '3';
}

echo '4';

// Prints 1234
```

Comment: it seems query throw exception itself

Comment: if your `query1` within the catch block throws another exception it won't be caught.

Comment: it seems it doesnt. but it seems query 2 run before query1 in catch block. i test it with microtime();

Comment: if i use true form of try catch, is it possible query2 run before query 1 in catch block beacause of waiting for locked row or query 2 wait for catch part?

Comment: No, php functions are blocking.